# Access gmail or yahoo mail using script

Tags: php, gmail, yahoo-mail

I was wondering how one would go about writing a php script to access mail from yahoo or gmail ?

Answer (score 4):

The "simplest" way would be to use [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP) to access the mails *(i.e. don't try any kind of HTML scraping !)*. I have no idea for Yahoo, but I know you can enable IMAP in gmail.

There are several libraries in PHP that allow one to use the IMAP protocol to access a mailbox ; for instance :

- There are functions provided in PHP *(You might have to install the extension, though)* : [IMAP, POP3 and NNTP](http://php.net/imap)
- Or you could use something like [`Zend_Mail`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zend Framework [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) functionality, this would allow you to connect to GMail/Yahoo/etc with POP3 or IMAP.

Comment: Pascal MARTIN got there before me.

Answer (score 0):

One more to add to Pascal's suggestions: [libgmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-lite/)